# C# .. API httpclient authentication and proxy with username and password

Tags: c#, api

I'm new in API's world but I had a question,
I want to get data from Web API but there's **two authentication**

- First with proxy.
- Second with API base authentication.

here's my Get Action code:

```
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "testing");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.abctesting.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("admin/apiv2/").Result;
        var tenders = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<tenders>().Result;
```

**this code work fine with me but just in pass over proxy username and password!
How can I continue to Get API Data with authentication username and password?**

Comment: Do you know which authentication mode your API is using?

Comment: Basic authentication I think

Answer (score 6):

Since you mentioned **"Basic Auth"** on comments adding the following lines in addition to what you have might help

```
 var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{yourUsername}:{yourPassword}");
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

Although there are other popular modes of auth such as `OAuth`, `Bearer` etc. Change the key on `AuthenticationHeaderValue` according to the mode of authentication and set the value appropriately

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "testing");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.abctesting.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string user = "user", password = "password";

string userAndPasswordToken =
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user + ":" + password));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", 
    $"Basic {userAndPasswordToken}");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("admin/apiv2/").Result;
var tenders = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<tenders>().Result;
```

Comment: it got 3 errors ..
 .. unexpected charachter $
 .. invalid expression term ''
 .. ) expected